# Lost my italian refugee travel document

Tags: resident-permit, italy, documentation, refugees

I lost my italain refugee travel document and asilo politico ( resid. Permit card ) . It will be expire december 2019.  If i apply new one, will get until dec 2019 or for example apply application may 2019 to may 2024? Will be new expire day 2024 ?

Comment: Unclear whether you're asking about the term of a new refugee travel document, or the term of a new *asilo politico.*

Comment: I lost both of. When i apply new permesso di soggiorno and travel documents will get until december 2019. Or will get new 5 years document.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But because you must replace these documents...the answer doesn't matter: if you want a longer term, ask for it. I think it's likely, however, that you have no power to command a particular term, and will receive replacement documents with whatever term is usually given by the documents office.

Comment: This is far less about travel than it is about living in a country other than your own, so it belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: So ?...........